# Matlab usage of the function fitnlm

Tags: matlab

I am using the function  fitnlm :

`f= @(a,x)(a(1)*log(x+a(2)));
mod= NonLinearModel.fit(A,B,f,[3,1])`

for some data points (A,B)).

The output is
[image]

I am having a problem how to get separately the values of `a(1)` and `a(2)` to use them in an internal  matlab function.  Does anay one know how can I get  them  ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Upon calling NonLinearModel.fit, you get a NonLinearModel object out. What you want is probably one of the properties of this object. So look at the class documentation: https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/nonlinearmodel-class.html It looks like what you want is (taking the variable names from your code excerpt) mod.Coefficients.Estimate. Note that this is really a programming question so that it is not really suitable for MSE.

Comment: Another useful page [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/nonlinear-regression-workflow.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [MATLAB documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/nonlinearmodel-class.html):

"Coefficient values, stored as a table. Coefficients has one row for each coefficient and the following columns" (as in the output of your model). "To obtain any of these columns as a vector, index into the property using dot notation."

Hence, in your example, the coefficients would be found in:

a = mod.Coefficients.Estimate